# When to use generics and type checking?

Tags: c#, generics, reflection

Assume `A` through `Z` to be 26 classes I defined.  In the following example:

```
  private List<A> _listA;
  private List<B> _listB;
  // private List<C>, and so on, through...
  private List<Z> _listZ;

  private void setLabelA()
  {
      LabelA.Text = _listA.Count;
  }

  // private void setLabelB() exists
  // and so does setLabelC()
  // and so on, all the way through to...

  private void setLabelZ()
  {
      LabelA.Text = _listZ.Count;
  }
```

It seems to me that there is no way to shorten this other than the following:

```
  private void setLabel<genericType>(List<genericType> list)
  {
      if(list is List<A>)      LabelA.Text = _listA.Count;
      else if(list is List<B>) LabelB.Text = _listB.Count;
      else if(list is List<C>) LabelC.Text = _listC.Count;
      //  and so on...
      else if(list is List<Z>) LabelZ.Text = _listZ.Count;
  }
```

Overloading the function name doesn't reduce the number of lines of code:

```
  private void setLabel(List<A> list)
  {
      LabelA.Text = _listA.Count;
  }

  private void setLabel(List<B> list)
  {
      LabelB.Text = _listB.Count;
  }
```

I prefer to use the `is` operator to determine which `Label` to set, because it preserves space (in this scenario, 50 lines of meaningless brackets and 25 lines of slightly-different function names).  *However*, a Stack Overflow user recommended that I **not** use generics, and instead use separate functions, one for each `Label`.  Although this solution will work, I prefer to not do so.

Is there any benefit towards **NOT** using the `is` operator, and towards explicitly typing my functions?

Comment: Delete  all that and use DataBinding, whatever you're trying to do.

Comment: but why you not use passed parmeter `list`? also what you use? winforms? wpf? what is `LabelA`?

Comment: @HighCore I'm not actually working with WinForms or `Labels`, it was just the first idea I could think of to illustrate this concept.  But DataBinding is definitely new to me, and after reading a little bit about it, I will make sure I incorporate it in the future.  Thanks!

Comment: Is LabelA a static class?  Is it some sort of member variable?  What is it?  Based on your answer there are actually other ways of solving what you are trying to do.  Will all of the item types implement a specific interface or subclass a particular base class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The benefit is that your type checking is static, rather than dynamic.  If someone passes in a `List<SomeRandomeClassYouDontSupport>` to the first method, then the code will compile and just not work properly at runtime.  It'll either do nothing, throw an exception, or whatever you code it to do, but the point is that the caller won't be able to see that they did something wrong *until they run the code*.

When you have multiple overloads then the validation is done *at compile time*.  If an unsupported type is provided then *the code won't even compile* rather than compiling and not working.

It's also an important semantic difference.  Generics are there to say, "This method will work *regardless of what the type is*".  When creating a list there are no right and wrong type arguments to provide.  You can create a list of *any type that you want*.  That's an appropriate use of generics, because lists are a conceptually generic data structure.  Having several overloads is a way of saying, "This finite list of types is supported."  You're in the latter case, so that makes that behavior clearer to the caller, so they'll understand what the method needs to do *just by looking at its signature*.

Having said all of that, it looks like this isn't even a situation where you should be doing either.  If you really wanted to have a method accepting one of a finite number of types known at compile time as a parameter, overloads are the right way to do it, but in your case, you shouldn't be doing any of this at all.  You should be binding these UI compontents to a view as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31686121/when-to-use-generics-and-type-checking/31686183#comment51314082_31686121).

Comment: Thanks!  I see exactly what you mean.  For example, if a new class is created, such as `class AA` (and the corresponding list, etc), then another developer won't know to add the label to the generic function until they compile and (hopefully) get an exception message.  Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: There is an issue with your statement 'Generics are there to say, "This method will work regardless of what the type is".'  Constraints allow Generics to say, "This method will work with any type that satisfies 'n' constraints."  If the items that setLabel should work with all subclass the same type or implement the same interface, then he could potentially create the methods that he is looking to create.  And it would be better than creating overloads if they really all should be handled the same way.  The question is what is LabelA.  Is it a member variable, a static class or something else?

Comment: @TyreeJackson But there is no set of constraints here; he just has a static list of types he's trying to support.  And since he needs to know how to handle each type at compile time, as each is handled differently, he couldn't artificially create a set of constraints as that would mean an arbitrary number of possible types.

Comment: @Servy I don't think we know conclusively whether or not the list of types that he's trying to support share a common base class or interface since the author failed to enumerate them.  I was only taking issue with your statement regarding generics in a very general sense outside of the scope of this issue.  If the author can introduce a constraint, then that would work potentially better than writing a bunch of overloads.

Comment: @TyreeJackson It's *irrelevant* if they share a base type.  He's doing a completely different thing with each one.  Even if they *do* share a base type, he can't write a single implementation that will work for every derived type of that base type, because the implementation is just a list of checks against a type and an implementation specific to that type.  If they all share a base class and that constraint is used, but a new derived type of that base class is created, it wouldn't work if passed into this method unless this method is modified to specifically support it individually.

Comment: @Servy Whether or not he is doing something completely different with each one is also unclear. From the examples he provided, it seems that he is simply setting the text of some corresponding label for each type.  Unfortunately, since he does not indicate if the Label* are themselves types, instance variables, etc, we can't know if Label* is directly related to Type* where (Type is A, B, C, etc).  This is why I asked my question directly on the post. I could easily contrive an example using a pair of base types and a couple of constraints could handle some routing similar to what he is doing.

Answer (score 0):

I will NOT comment about whether it is a good practice or not to do what you are doing :).

If the absence of a label for a given list is NOT the end of the world for you and if you rely on some naming conventions for your label fields so that all labels are named for example "LabelX" where X is your type that will be used for generic lists, you can do that:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Labels
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Container c = new Container();
        c.ApplyLabels();
    }
}

public class A
{
}

public class B
{
}

public class C
{
}
public class Container
{
    private Label LabelA = new Label ();
    private Label LabelB = new Label ();
    private Label LabelC = new Label ();

    private List<A> _listA = new List<A> ();
    private List<B> _listB = new List<B> ();
    private List<C> _listC = new List<C> ();

    public void ApplyLabels ()
    {
        var allFields = this.GetType().GetFields(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

        Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo> listFields = new Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo>();
        Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo> labelMappings = new Dictionary<Type, FieldInfo>();
        Dictionary<string, Type> namespacesForListGenericTypes = new Dictionary<string, Type>();

        List<FieldInfo> possibleLabelFields = new List<FieldInfo>();
        foreach (var field in allFields)
        {
            if (field.FieldType.IsGenericType)
            {
                var genericTypeDef = field.FieldType.GetGenericTypeDefinition();

                if (genericTypeDef == typeof (List<>))
                {
                    var genericArgument = field.FieldType.GetGenericArguments()[0];
                    listFields.Add(genericArgument, field); // remember list fields and for each list what generic type it has!

                    namespacesForListGenericTypes[genericArgument.Name] = genericArgument;
                }
            }
            else if (typeof (Label).IsAssignableFrom (field.FieldType))
            {
                possibleLabelFields.Add(field);
            }
        }

        foreach (var possible in possibleLabelFields)
        {
            if (possible.Name.Length < 6) continue;

            var typeName = possible.Name.Substring(5);

            Type genericListType;
            if (namespacesForListGenericTypes.TryGetValue (typeName, out genericListType))
            {
                labelMappings[genericListType] = possible;
            }
        }

        foreach (var list in listFields)
        {
            FieldInfo destination;

            if (false == labelMappings.TryGetValue (list.Key, out destination))
            {
                continue;
            }

            var destinationLabel = destination.GetValue(this) as Label;
            if (destinationLabel == null) continue;

            var listValue = list.Value.GetValue(this) as IList;
            var cnt = listValue == null ? 0 : listValue.Count;

            destinationLabel.Text = cnt.ToString();
        }
    }
}

public class Label
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}
}
```

Comment: Generally talking, it is a problem of mappings between generics by making use of some patterns. For example, Imagine that you have an injection container and you have to write this: container.Add <ISomething, Something> (); container.Add <IAnotherThing, AnotherThing> (); and so on. It is obvious that this is a pattern and you would like to "map" automatically all classes named X to be the implementation for IX. To do that you will have to rely on reflection / meta programming to achieve this behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just make your own classes which derive their own fields automatically?

```
private class ListWithText : List<T>
{
    int Text {
        get { return this.Count; }
    }
}

ListWithText<A> LabelA = new ListWithText<A>();
Console.WriteLine(LabelA.Text);
```